# pagination /page/2 redirects to home page (domain.com)

Tags: pagination, redirect

Either using wp-pagenavi or the standard wp pagination (posts_nav_link()) a click to mydomain.com/page/2 will result in a 301 redirect back to the home page (url = domain.com )

This is not a duplicate, the other post talks nothing about redirects.  Also, my wp_query seems fine, as it works with pretty permalinks off.  Also, this whole thing works on at least one site with identical plugins and theme, etc.

UPDATE: http://domain.com/category/validCategory/page/2/ does work...

turning off pretty permalinks and using ?page=2 works.

Yes, I am using

```
$args['paged'] = get_query_var( 'page' );
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$posts = $wp_query->posts;
```

to modify the posts.

if I make it

```
$args['paged'] = 2;
```

It will show the second page of posts, but on the home page.

Yes, I have read several articles about not using a new query, but have determined that it is better for me if I do.

However, this redirection is happening before it ever gets to this, afaik.  I'm sticking a die() in there but it doesnt die until it's redirected, and dies on the home page.

Nothing in my htaccess would do this

```
php_value max_execution_time 3600
#php_flag display_errors on
#php_value error_reporting 7
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 20M

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*) /uploads/$1 [QSA,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

This is a new problem, only occuring on a couple of sites out of many that are running on identical installs.  I dont see any differences between working and non working.

So, if no one has the easy answer, where do I start to debug and find out where wp is deciding it needs to redirect to home?

Comment: I fixed it with the template_redirect filter: http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-disable-wordpress-canonical-url-or-permalink-auto-redirect/  But I'd love some more explanation as to why.

Comment: *Yes, I have read several articles about not using a new query, but have determined that it is better for me if I do.* There is no legitimate reason I can imagine where doing this is necessary. Move whatever query modification you need to do into a function hooked to [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts), do not modify the query in the template.

Comment: answer #7 of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts However, I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: again, it is normally not necessary and not advised to do it that way when using `pre_get_posts` is much simpler. the issue is that the *main query* and your template query are totally unrelated. WordPress decides whether or not to send a 404 and if a redirect is necessary based on the results of the main query, which happens long before the template is ever loaded. in some cases, like displaying posts on the `page` post type, you'll find it works ok, but in many cases it doesn't.

Comment: why you find it works in some installs and not others is not because of theme or plugin differences, it's because the *content* is different, so the results of the default main query are different.

Comment: have a look at the [action reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference), this is the order of steps WP goes through while loading a page. `parse_request` through `posts_selection` is where the actual contents of a page are loaded, and where WP decides if there's anything to display, but we don't get to displaying them until a few steps later after the `template_redirect` action. when you're trying to manipulate the main query in the template, you're already several steps too late in the process to successfully handle all cases.

Comment: Using pre_get_posts doesnt solve the problem in the linked question/answer#7 above, though does it?  If I alter the query args before I get the posts, I wont know that I am 'on a page of posts'... because it hasnt gotten the post yet, Or does it?

Comment: the one specific case I mentioned above is if you're trying to show posts on a page post type, but if this is your home page that doesn't apply here. the info you've provided isn't really enough to discern exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm only doing a replacement query if($postname == 'home') So that I can use that fact and the info from the 'home' post.  Basically, my list of non categorized posts is showing on the home page.  I played with this for some hours, I think I wasnt able to get is_front_page() to work with pre_get_posts. I have several other reasons on each page where I need to know if I am at 'home'.  I appreciate your time here, and would def quit using a new query if I could figure a couple things out.